# Converting strange lat/lng format to decimal

Tags: gps, rgeo

I have a device reporting its position to me in a format they describe as 'ddmm.mmmm'

it looks like this:

Latitude: 5108.5837 N
Longitude: 00052.6334 E

Anyone have an idea how I can convert this to a normal decimal number that I can use with RGeo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've worked it out, for anyone that may come across the same format, its simpler than I thought it was..

```
Latitude: 5108.5812 N
Longitude: 00052.6289 E
```

degrees is anything before the last 2 digits before the decimal point (e.g. 51 or 000)

minutes is the rest, seconds are expressed as fractional minutes so you just have to do:

```
51.0 + (8.5812 / 60.0) = 51.14302
0.0 + (52.6289 / 60.0) = 0.8771483333
```

if the latitude is S, negate it

if the longitude is W, negate it

For reference, if you have seconds too, you'd do:

```
degrees + (minutes.to_f / 60) + (seconds.to_f / 3600)
```

There are some degrees, 60 minutes is 1 degree, 60 seconds is 1 minute (60*60 = 3600)